# wireless sniffing using pcap, MAC address filter

Tags: capture, monitor, wireless, mode, pcap

I am writing a wireless packet sniffer program in C. I have set my wireless interface in monitor mode using airmon-ng, and now i am sniffing on the interface "mon0". I am using linux(ubuntu 10.10).

I want to set MAC address as the filter for the packets. 
I have done it as shown below, but it says
"mon0 no IPV4 address assigned"

```
 pcap_lookupnet(dev,&net,&mask,errbuf);
    printf("%s\n",errbuf);
    /* Open the session in promiscuous mode */
    handle = pcap_open_live(dev, BUFSIZ, 1, 1000, errbuf);
    if (handle == NULL) {
        printf("Couldn't open device %s: %s\n", dev, errbuf);
        return 2;
    }
    if(pcap_compile(handle,&fp,argv[0],0,net)==-1){
        fprintf(stderr,"Error calling pcap_compile\n");exit(1);}
    if(pcap_setfilter(handle,&fp) == -1){
        fprintf(stderr,"Error setting filter\n");exit(1);}
    /* The call pcap_loop() and pass our callback function */
    pcap_loop(handle, 10, my_callback, NULL);
```

Please help me, how i can set the filter for MAC address??

Answer (score 5):

"no IPV4 address assigned" is an error from `pcap_lookupnet()`.  All it means is that the network interface on which you're trying to capture does not have an IPv4 address assigned to it.  What `airmon-ng` did was to create a "monitor" interface for the Wi-Fi adapter; the regular network interface for the adapter might have an IP address assigned to it, but the monitor interface won't have one.

The *only* place where the IP address matters is for `ip broadcast` filter expressions; if you're not filtering for IPv4 broadcast addresses, which you probably won't be, there's no need to get the IPv4 address.  To quote the `pcap_compile()` man page:

> If the netmask of the network on which packets are being captured isn't known to the  program, or if packets are being captured on the Linux "any" pseudo-interface that can capture on more than one network, a value of 0 can be supplied; tests for IPv4 broadcast  addreses won't be done correctly, but all other tests in the filter program will be OK.

so just pass 0 as the "net" argument to `pcap_compile()`.

If you want to search for packets being sent to a particular MAC address, you can just use `wlan dst XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX`; if you want to search for packets being sent *from* a particular MAC address, you can just use `wlan src XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX`; if you want to search for packets being sent to or from a particular MAC address, you can just use `wlan host XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX`.  If you care about the access point address, rather than the station address, you'll need to use filters such as `wlan ra XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX` or `wlan ta XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX`, at least with newer versions of libpcap.  (See the pcap-filter man page or, if you don't have a pcap-filter man page, the tcpdump man page for details.)

Comment: I read your tutorials on tcpdump's webpage. and I try to learn by reading what you wrote on stackoverflow. do you have any webpage that you published more instructions about the libpcap?